# How to implement Auth0 SSO in Cordova without Angular

Tags: javascript, cordova, single-sign-on, cordova-plugins, auth0

I am working on a Cordova Application where it uses only HTML, javascript, and jQuery. I need to implement Auth0 SSO in my application. I came to see all examples are done only in Angular, But I need to implement them in javascript.
Anyone who implemented Auth0 SSO with javascript, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

For every need there's a Cordova plugin. In this case, the [auth0-cordova plugin](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-cordova) is the first one I found, probably there are others too. Does not require Ionic nor Angular, just vanilla Apache Cordova.

Comment: But tried this option also. but unable to achieve the result. Any other opinion @andreszs